# Delete rows in dataframe based on info from Series

Tags: pandas, series

I would like to delete all rows in the Dataframe that have number of appereance = 10 and status = 1. 
Example of Dataframe X is

```
    ID      Status 
0   366804  0   
1   371391  1   
2   383537  1   
3   383538  0   
4   383539  0
```

...

First I found all rows with status=1 with count()=10
exclude=X[X.Status == 1].groupby('ID')['Status'].value_counts().loc[lambda x: x==10].index

exclude is Series
MultiIndex([(   371391, 1),
            (   383537, 1),
            ... 
Is it possible to delete rows in Dataframe X based od info for ID from Series ?

Comment: could you add a expected output?

Comment: can you please add expected output

Answer (score 1):

If your original DataFrame looks something like this:

```
print(df)
        ID  Status
0   366804       0
1   371391       1
2   383537       1
3   383538       0
4   383539       0
5   371391       1
6   371391       1
7   371391       1
8   371391       1
9   371391       1
10  371391       1
11  371391       1
12  371391       1
13  371391       1
```

And you group IDs and statuses together to find the IDs you want to exclude:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['ID', 'Status']).size().to_frame('size').reset_index()
print(df2)                                                                                
       ID  Status  size
0  366804       0     1
1  371391       1    10
2  383537       1     1
3  383538       0     1
4  383539       0     1

excludes = df2.loc[(df2['size'] == 10) & (df2['Status'] == 1), 'ID']
print(excludes)                                                                           
1    371391
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Then you could use [`Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html#pandas.Series.isin) and invert the boolean Series [`~s`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[~df['ID'].isin(excludes)]

print(df)                                                                                 
       ID  Status
0  366804       0
2  383537       1
3  383538       0
4  383539       0
```